# Nginx url GET parameter with proxy_pass

Tags: url, nginx, proxy, get

I get this url in my nginx server:

http://mynginx.com/proxy?url=http://target.com

And I want to proxy through that nginx server, so that it retrieves http://target.com

I am currently using this in my nginx configuration:

```
location /proxy {
    proxy_pass $arg_url
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

For some reason it response with a "502 Bad Gateway"

Can some tell what is the appropiate configuration for this problem?

And why nginx response with 502 error?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad, I was not using the resolver in my configuration:

`location /proxy {
   resolver 8.8.8.8;
   proxy_pass $arg_url
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
}`